# Do something when Excel Query has finished

Tags: excel, vba

I Query data from web with excel and want to do some formatting when the query has finished. I found a snippet on Microsoft help page but it do not work:

```
Sub all_refresh()
'
' all_refresh Makro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Abfrage - Umrechnung").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Abfrage - Übersicht").Refresh

    With Sheets("All").QueryTables(1)  ' <<<<<here I get the error
      If .Refreshing Then
        MsgBox "Query is currently refreshing: please wait"
      Else
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .ResultRange.Select
      End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: error]

That means something like:
Excel can not find the "QueryTables(1)" but I do not know how to select the right one by name or something else!

Comment: I have updated my question and added the position

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Sheets("All").QueryTables.Count` give you? Is there at least one in that sheet? And are you sure you have a sheet called `All` in the active workbook?

Comment: Good idea. it return "0". Hmm I do not know how to select these Query to get the .refreshing status. Yest I Have a sheet called "All"

Comment: It sounds to me like they are not `QueryTables` like you think then, or you have the wrong sheet.

Comment: me too :) "ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Abfrage - Umrechnung").Refresh" do a webquery and the output go to my sheet "All". is there a other way to "do something" when "ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Abfrage - Umrechnung").Refresh" has finished?

Comment: I Have it I have Uncheck the "Enable Background Refresh" in the Data -> Connection -> Properties
This will disable refresh in background and wait for Refresh to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to uncheck the "Enable Background Refresh" in the Data -> Connection -> Properties

This will disable refresh in background and wait for Refresh to complete.

After that this will work:

```
Sub all_refresh()

  '
  ' all_refresh Makro
  '

  ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Abfrage - Umrechnung").Refresh
  ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Abfrage - Übersicht").Refresh

  'Do Something cool
  MsgBox ("The Refreshing is Completed!")
End Sub
```